# Using junction.exe for Windows 8 only creates a directory to copy to and is not protecting the targetted directory

Tags: windows-8, ssd, ntfs, ntfs-junction, directory-junction

I am using `junction.exe` for Windows 8 with commands like these

```
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe D:\Temp\Sandbox\ C:\Sandbox\
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe D:\Temp\AppData C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe D:\Temp\Windows\System32 C:\Windows\System32\
```

I am trying to use junction.exe to extend the life of my SSD as described here http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd

but it seems that files are being written to BOTH the SSD and to the HDD where I put the junction point. Am I doing something wrong or do I have a misconception of what a junction point does?

So for example I open Sandboxie, and log, cache, other files get written to both the HDD (D:\Temp\Sandbox) AND my SSD (C:\Sandbox). I'd like the writing to occur only on my HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Junction Points were suppose to be created in the opposite direction

```
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe C:\Sandbox\ D:\Temp\Sandbox\
```

so that all of the files writing to C: will go to D: instead